# When taking the integral of $\sec(x)$, how do you come up with the crucial step?

Tags: integration, secant

You have to multiply with $\frac{\sec(x) + \tan(x)}{\sec(x) + \tan(x)}$ (http://math2.org/math/integrals/more/sec.htm), but how do you come up with this idea? Is there a specific reason for that step, or is it just mathematical intuition?

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions, they come out in the right font and spacing, so \sec(x) gives $\sec (x)$

Comment: It t[ook a long time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_the_secant_function) for that particular integral to be solved.  So I'd say you really just have to guess it.  But once you've seen it, you understand why it is good guess given you know the antiderivatives of $\sec^2(x)$ and $\sec(x)\tan(x)$.

Answer (score 21):

Before I learned about $\sec(x)$, the way I used to integrate $\frac{1}{\cos x}$ is to multiply with $\frac{\cos x}{\cos x}$ and substitute $u = \sin x$. You may find that a bit more "natural".

Comment: Oh, well that was an interestingly simple answer.

Comment: Nice way, for sure !

Comment: Isaac Barrow would certainly approve (see Bye_World's link).

Comment: @PaulSinclair Yes indeed.  ;D

Comment: Here's a link to the method mentioned: https://www.math.ubc.ca/~feldman/m121/secx.pdf

Answer (score 10):

Well, we want to multiply it by some $\frac{f(x)}{f(x)}$ so that $f'(x)=\sec(x)f(x)$ for the $u$-sub.

Let $f(x)$ be of the form $g(x)+h(x)$.  We'd want to find some $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ such that $\sec(x)g(x)$ and $\sec(x)h(x)$ have known antiderivatives.

Hm... so what derivatives do we know of that involve $\sec(x)$ multiplied by something...?

Well, that's not particularly hard...

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sec(x)=\sec(x)\tan(x)$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan(x)=\sec^2(x)$$

So we would have $g(x)=\tan(x)$ and $h(x)=\sec(x)$, giving us our $f(x)$.

Then the rest is easy.